# How can i use jersey and Amazon AWS (elastic beanstalk) together

Tags: java, json, rest, amazon-web-services, jersey

I'm trying to debug a rest/json service that i build using Jersey and Amazon AWS. I intend to run it on ElasticBeanstalk.

The project is created using the AWS plugin for eclipse as a new Aws Java Web project. I then downloaded jersey and dumped the jars in WEB-INF/lib.

The runtime error i get is

> class "org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException"'s signer information does not match >signer information of other classes in the same package

I suspect some sort of clash with aws. If i change the build path order (moving things up and down the list in eclipse->build path->order and export tab) i get other errors. (specifically i can get the jersey to work by moving it up the list but then aws breaks)

I hope someone has done something similar and is able to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove jackson-core-asl-*.jar from your classpath, it's already part of the AWS SDK.